# Redhat Linux: How to know my system configuration?

Tags: linux, rhel, configuration, command

I am using `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.9 (Tikanga)`.
For installation of any application, it is very important to know the system configuration, is it 32 bit or 64 bit system, Installed OS is 32 bit or 64 bit etc... 
Is there any command which provides me information about my system configuration just like Windows provide when go to `Control Panel\System and Security\System`.

Please suggest...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `uname`:

```
uname -i
```

For more information, see

```
man uname
```

If you get `x86`, it means you have 32 bit Linux OS and if you get `x86_64`, it means you have 64 bit Linux.

Comment: I got x86_64 when run uname -m;uname-p;uname-i; Does this mean that I have 64 bit system? How can I know that my OS is 64 bit or 32 bit?

Comment: It means your kernel is 64 bit and in most cases your OS is 64 bit. If you get x86, it means your os is 32 bit.

Comment: @usitesion: `uname` is giving information about your system. So in this case it **does** mean you have a 64 bit OS

Answer (score 2):

you can use this command:

```
cat /etc/issue; cat /proc/cpuinfo ; uname -a
```

Comment: I don't really see the point regarding `/etc/issue`: this is a user level only information message defined by the system admins (ex: legal warning for company servers).